# How can I save image in subfolder using Amazon aws3 | Laravel

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3

I am using aws to store my images and the code in the controller looks like this:

```
Storage::disk('3')->put($file->getClientOriginalName(), fopen($file, 'r+'), 'public');
```

The images are being saved in my local storage.
Now though, I want to be able to create a subfolder to keep the images organized.

For my case, it is registering a business. Therefore I want the images to be stored in a subfolder containing the appropriate business id. I tried this:

```
Storage::disk('3')->put($file->getClientOriginalName(), fopen($file, 'r+'), 'public/' . $business->id.
```

More about the controller is as follows:

```
$input              = $request->all();

$files              = isset($input['file']) ? $input['file'] : array ();
$business_names     = json_decode($input['business_names'], true);
$business_details   = json_decode($input['business_details']);
$share_amount       = json_decode($input['share_amount'], true);
$entity             = json_decode($input['entity'], true);
$directors          = json_decode($input['directors'], true);
$shareholders       = json_decode($input['shareholders'], true);
$appointments       = json_decode($input['appointments'], true);

$input['user_id'] = Auth::user()->id;

Log::info(Auth::user());
Log::info($request->user());
/* Create Business Record */
$business = new Business;
$business->business_names = json_encode($business_names);
$business->share_amount = $share_amount ?: 0;
$business->entity = $entity ?: '';
$business->business_physical_address = json_encode($business_details->physical_address);
$business->has_business_postal_address = $business_details->has_postal_address;
$business->business_postal_address = json_encode($business_details->postal_address);
$business->user_id = $input['user_id'];
$business->save();

/* Create a new folder in storage/app/files named after the business ID */
Storage::makeDirectory('files/' . $business->id);

/* Upload Files */
// TODO: file storing?
foreach($files as $file) {
    if ($file) {
        Storage::disk('3')->put($file->getClientOriginalName(), fopen($file, 'r+'), 'public/' . $business->id);
        // $file->storeAs('files/' . $business->id, $file->getClientOriginalName());
    }
}
```

When I try to save a business now, I see the following error:

> C:\xampp\htdocs\startingabandbaby\vendor\league\flysystem\src\Adapter\Local.php(356):
>   Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(8,
>   'Undefined index...', 'C:\xampp\htdocs...', 356, Array)

Since I was able to store images before, I am assuming that it is something to do with concatenating the business id.

How can I create a subfolder with the business id everytime I create a new business and add all the files in that same folder?

Comment: Use it this way: `Storage::makeDirectory('files/' . $business->id, 0777,true);`

Comment: but how do I do the same to create the files at aws?

Comment: Use this: `Storage::disk('s3')->putFileAs('files/' . $business->id, $request->file('gif'), ['visibility' => 'public']);`

Answer (score 1):

As per our discussion, you can use below 2 solutions:

1) [put()](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Contracts/Filesystem/Filesystem.html#method_put):

```
$path = Storage::disk('s3')->put(
                    '/files/'. $business->id, //path you want to upload image to S3
                    file_get_contents($request->file('file')), //fileContent
                   'public' //visibility
```

2) [putFileAs()](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Filesystem/FilesystemAdapter.html#method_putFileAs): To achieve the same thing withputFileAs(), I needed to write it as below. 1st parameter expects the directory name, I left it blank as I'm mimicking the directory name in s3 through the filename.

```
$path = Storage::disk('s3')->putFileAs(
                '', // 1st parameter expects directory name, I left it blank as I'm mimicking the directory name through the filename
                '/files/'. $business->id,
                $request->file('file'), //3rd parameter file resource
                ['visibility' => 'public'] //options
            );
```

Hope this will helps you!

Answer (score 0):

After some research I ended up with the following:

```
$directory = 'public/' . $business->id;
Storage::disk()->makeDirectory($directory);

foreach($files as $file) {
    if ($file) {
        Storage::disk()->put($directory . '/' .$file->getClientOriginalName(), fopen($file, 'r+'));                   
    }
}
```